# How to get multi select in started gallery in android

Tags: android

G'day!

I want to start gallery with multi select mode, but I was failed.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

and I added the next:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

for get images from gallery, but it work only I start gallery as app and select files there.

How can I start gallery with multi select mode from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, You can't. As Android Native Gallery application is only responds for Single Select response with Intent `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

For Multi Selection mode you have to use Either some File-Manager or write your own File-Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Since API18, you actually can use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to select multiple items now using `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE

Comment: Unfortunately, It works since 18. How do I use that for API less than 18? =)

Comment: like the selected answer have pointed out, you can't :< I was just letting people know that the extra now exists, because this definite no was given in 2012 before API18

Comment: Please hep i am doing this in api 18 but i cant able to select multiple images from gallery... Can you please provide sample code here.